# Angular 2, routing, redirects and lazy-loading issue

Tags: angular, routes

I’m having an issue with routing in Angular 2.0.0: I have a marketing page with a button to access a logged in section. When I click that button, I want to load a MyModule whose routes look like that:

```
const myRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: MyComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
       { path: '', redirectTo: '/benefits', pathMatch: 'full'},
       { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/my/admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]},
       { path: 'budget', loadChildren: 'app/my/budget/budget.module#BudgetModule', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]},
       { path: 'benefits', loadChildren: 'app/my/benefits/benefits.module#BenefitsModule', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]}
   ]}
];
```

But when I click that button, I get an error in the console saying that:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'benefits'
   at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:77580:16)
   at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:77572:29)
```

Is there a problem with redirects and lazy-loading or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm facing same problem. Did you find issue?